# GoogleAuthR package giving an issue while downloading a spreadsheet from google drive

Tags: r, shiny, google-authentication, google-docs-api

I am trying to implement the google authentication and interact with the google drive(read and write files, folders, spreadsheets).

I am successfully able to authenticate and read the list of files from google drive but facing an issue while downloading a file.

Here is the code snippet:

```
gar_api_generator(paste0("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/",
                          file_id, "/export"),
                          "GET",
                          pars_args=list(
                          mimeType = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"),
                          data_parse_function = NULL)()
```

and here is the error I am getting:

```
       Warning: Error in : API returned: Export only supports Google Docs.
```

Can any help me with it?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `googlesheets` package to work directly with the spreadsheet?

Comment: No, since I want to show the list of folders as well, and I doubt googlesheets will provide those details.